# Is there a way to solve: `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

**CHECK THE ERROR AND THE COMMANDS I RUN AT THE END OF IT**

=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...

- Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
- Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
- Environment: development
  Exiting
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  44: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>' 43: from ./bin/rails:3:in` load'
  42: from /home/mvmarco/code/mvmarco/portfolio/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>' 41: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
  40: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 39: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in` <top (required)>'
  38: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load' 37: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in` <top (required)>'
  36: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run' 35: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in` call'
  34: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call' 33: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in` load'
  32: from /home/mvmarco/code/mvmarco/portfolio/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>' 31: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in` require'
  30: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency' 29: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in` block in require'
  28: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require' 27: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in` require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  26: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register' 25: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  24: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require' 23: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in` '
  22: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke' 21: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in` perform'
  20: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' 19: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
  18: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' 17: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in` perform'
  16: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap' 15: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in` block in perform'
  14: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start' 13: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in` start'
  12: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run' 11: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in` run'
  10: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/single.rb:98:in `run' 9: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/runner.rb:161:in` load_and_bind'
  8: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse' 7: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in` each'
  6: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:106:in `block in parse' 5: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:222:in` add_tcp_listener'
  4: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:222:in `each' 3: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:223:in` block in add_tcp_listener'
  2: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in `add_tcp_listener' 1: from /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in` new'
  /home/mvmarco/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.6/lib/puma/binder.rb:229:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

I get the above error. I tried to do:

1. **lsof -wni tcp:3000**       I GET: *NO RESULTS*
2. **ps aux | grep puma**
   I GET:
   *mvmarco   7805  0.0  0.0   6304   724 pts/0    S+   20:52  0:00 grep --color puma*
3. **kill -9 7805**      I GET: *kill: kill 7805 failed: no such process*
4. **kill PID**         I GET: *kill: illegal pid: PID*
5. **sudo fuser -k -n tcp port**     I GET: *Cannot resolve local port port: Servname not supported for ai_socktype*

EVERYTHING WAS WORKING BEFORE I DID A SETUP FOR MY INTERNSHIP, THEY USE DOCKER. I AM WONDERING HOW TO LET IT WORK AGAIN

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there is another instance of Puma still running. To kill it, I usually use:

```
pkill -9 -f puma
```

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: thanks a lot harisp9631 - if I do:
 http://127.0.0.1:3000/ it works. But only with the IP format. Before was working just typing localhost:3000 in the browser. Now only if it is IP format. Any clue?

Comment: @user14749773 By limited info, seems like an issue with etc/hosts file. But that is a separate question, you should ask it separately and close this one